# Collision detection with visualization in ROS

Tags: ros, collision

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was wondering if there are any existing stable support for collision
detection in ROS and if any, possibly some that are using the octree of the
Octomap library and allows for visualization in RVIZ? Currently it seems that collision detection through the motion_planning_environment stack has been placed into motion_planning_common; is motion_planning_common stable to use still? And if so, are there any resources such as tutorials that are available for setting up a self defined robot instead of the PR2?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10498/collision-detection-with-visualization-in-ros/) by [diannay](https://answers.ros.org/users/745/diannay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2011-07-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

In terms of stability we have not yet made any claims for any of the arm navigation stacks, including motion_planning_common.  A good deal of this software will be being released as stable in our forthcoming e-turtle release.  As part of the e-turtle release we have been developing a number of tools that attempt to make it easier to interact with the software.  Among these is an auto-configuration tool that should make it easier to get all of our software working for a new robot.  If you are interested you can try out the new tutorial, though it will require installing some software from our unstable debians.  The tutorial is here: [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/Automatically%20Generating%20Arm%20Navigation%20Configurations/Planning%20Description%20Configuration%20Wizard).  Again, this won't be stable until the e-turtle release, but definitely the easiest way forward to trying out our software.

In terms of displaying detected collisions in rviz we don't currently have a tool that will do that out of the box.  We're working on something like that, but it won't be available for a little while.

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2011-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3